# What is causing error "403 FORBIDDEN (Access not allowed even with authorization)" for new domain on Domino server?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, ibm-domino

With **Domino 9** server, a new **Virtual Hostname** doc has been added to the **Domino Directory** for domain **xxxxx.app**.  It is configured with default values, and there are several other web sites hosted on the server with the same configuration.  SSL is running on one of the domains, but all the rest are HTTP.

However, the site is not accessible via the browser giving the error message:

**403 FORBIDDEN (Access not allowed even with authorization)**

The only difference between this site and the others is that it has an **.app** high level domain name, and it was added to the Directory after the SSL key had been installed for a different domain name.

What may be causing forbidden access even with authorization?

Answer (score 0):

The .app domain names are forced by Chrome and Firefox to use HTTPS as per the conditions of their use (Google owns the .app high level domain name).

Since Domino allows only one HTTPS certificate per IP address, an HTTPS certificate must be installed for the .app domain.